# trouble with subscribing form (Django)

Tags: python, django

Please, help.. I do not udersatand what I should do this code to work..

home.html:

```
<form class="subscribe-form" action="{% url 'subscribe' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}

    <button class="btn btn-main btn-lg" type="submit">Подписаться!</button>
</form>

{% if success %}
<div class="subscribe-result">
    {{ success }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', 'interior_app.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^subscribe/$', 'interior_app.views.subscribe', name='subscribe')
```

models.py:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField('', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class SubscriberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscriber
        fields = ['email']
```

admin.py:

```
class SubscriberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email',)

admin.site.register(Subscriber, SubscriberAdmin)
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    portfolios = PortfolioObject.objects.all()
    photos = []
    for portfolio in portfolios:
        for obj in portfolio.photo_set.all():
            photos.append(obj)

    form = SubscriberForm()
    context = {"photos": photos[::2], "form": form}

    return render(request, "home.html", context)

def subscribe(request):
    print request
    success = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        print request.POST
        form = SubscriberForm(request.POST)
        print form
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            success = "Ваш Email успешно отправлен"
            form = SubscriberForm()
    else:
        form = SubscriberForm()

    context = {"photos": photos[::2], "form": form, "success": success}

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

I input email in the form, push button and nothing is happening.
Any data in admin, any {{ success }}.

I need not AJAX.. I would like to do this feature only with Django

Comment: Nothing happened? The page doesn't even refresh?

Comment: Does your server log says anything? http403? http500? If you open your browser console is there any error in there?

Comment: in the Chrome console:                                                                          GET http://cantothemes.us8.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post-json?u=37a0cb83e98c8…j4GbzWofNXebZNQXIXY35EeD23z94ttv&EMAIL=denzil%40bigmir.net&_=1452696902183

Comment: and:                                                                                                                  send @ jquery.min.js:5                                                                         m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:5                                                (anonymous function) @ jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js:1                            m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:4                                                          r.handle @ jquery.min.js:4

Comment: We need to see the *Django* logs, e.g. from `./manage.py runserver` if you are in your dev environment.

Comment: when manage.py runserver:                                                                     System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 13, 2016 - 21:33:30
Django version 1.9, using settings 'interior.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Comment: when input email in the form and push button --> nothing changes in the command line

Comment: THANKS! issue has been resolved